# Random Button Appearance not Working

Tags: c#, winforms

Warning, I'm very new to C#. Anyways, I have a random generator which picks a number, and if number x is picked then my x button would appear and it repeats. However this sometimes works and it sometimes doesn't. What I mean by this is a button is supposed to button1.Visible = true but when I click another button button 1 should go away and another one has to come, I need it to work with only one button visible but sometimes a button is not visible at all. It's weird.

Here's one button click:

```
private void A_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (ao.Visible == true)
    {
        ao.Visible = false;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int y = rnd.Next(1, 7);

        if (y == 1)
        {
            eo.Visible = true;
        }
        if (y == 2)
        {
            ao.Visible = true;
        }
        if (y == 4)
        {
            dd.Visible = true;
        }
        if (y == 5)
        {
            go.Visible = true;
        }
        if (y == 6)
        {
            eeo.Visible = true;
        }
        //     timer1.Stop();
        timer1.Start();

        label1.Text = "Correct";


    }

    else
    {

        label1.Text = "Incorrect";
    }
```

Button A is visible it would go to that event I just pasted and make it invisible and another one visible. Again sometimes nothing would be visible.

Comment: What about `y == 3`?

Comment: And this is why I warned you about me being new. Thank you so much lol... Edit: It still doesn't work

Comment: being new is not a valid excuse.. anyway.. what happens when you debug this vs just running it..? also what is the purpose of the `timer` in your code..? also why not refactor that code to utilize a `switch()case{}`

Comment: there's no errors, it just doesn't show up. It's random, sometimes I can get it to work for 20 tries straight and sometimes it doesn't appear after the first try. The timer should be commented out.

Comment: step thru the code and I am quite sure that you will see why it doesn't show up.. what do you expect to happen in the Else block.. for example like someone has mentioned already.. what if `y==3` If you wrote this code.. then you should be able to debug / fix the code.. this is what part of being a good developer is.. `Beginner or Not..`

Comment: You should definitely look into using a switch statement when comparing one value like that.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx

Comment: I changed the y == 3, doesn't seem to effect anything. When the else is used nothing is supposed to change, just the label

Comment: use a switch statement.. it will make reading this code much cleaner.. you can nest values in a single case by the way using the `:` as a separator. this is not that trivial.. also changing it does not help answer the question in regards to `Did you use the debugger` which I am more inclined to think you did not..also with ambiguous names for buttons such as `eo or eeo or go` perhaps you are confusing yourself.. make your names more meaninful

Comment: I will research more into switch statements. Anyways, I found my error I set the Random variable to cycle through 1,7 not 1,6 or just (7). Sorry, and yes I used the debugger. Thank you and sorry for causing trouble I need to work on proofreading

Comment: `Random.Next(int a, int b)` is exclusive on b. You should never get 7 with `Next(1, 7)`.

Comment: I think if you do Random.Next(7), you'll never get 7 but with (1,7) I think you do? Not sure but it seems to of fixed my problem.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm going to stop embarrassing myself ugh,

Comment: Creating a `new Random()` every time you click could bias your results. Make `rnd` an instance variable and instantiate it in your constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your description you say you want the button to disappear again, but you are never setting `Visible` to false again. In this case I wouldn't actually use a switch.

```
class RandomButtonForm : Form
{
    private Random rng;
    private List<Button> buttons;

    public RandomButtonForm()
    {
        this.rng = new Random();

        this.buttons = new List<Button>();
        this.AddButton(10, 10, "Button 1");
        this.AddButton(110, 10, "Button 2");
        this.AddButton(210, 10, "Button 3");
    }

    public AddButton(int x, int y, string text)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Visible = false;
        button.X = x;
        button.Y = y;
        button.Text = text;
        this.buttons.Add(button);
        this.Controls.Add(button);
    }

    private void A_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int r = this.rng.Next(this.buttons.Count);

        for (int b = 0; b < this.buttons.Count; b++)
        {
            this.buttons[b].Visible = (b == r);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead this actually uses a direct comparison to provide a boolean value for each button. A simple example of this this would be:

```
ao.Visible = (y == 1);
// (y == 1) is either true or false.
```

This means that not only does the button get shown if the value is 1, it gets HIDDEN if the value is not one, allowing you to press your "go" button over and over.

This example also includes some other useful things such as a `List<Button>` and automatically using the Count of that for your random, making maintaining it easier if you need to change the number of buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about everything that's going on in your code, but it seems like you want only one of the buttons to be visible at a time.  If so, then do something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Random rnd = new Random();
    private List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttons.Add(ao);
        buttons.Add(eo);
        buttons.Add(dd);
        buttons.Add(go);
        buttons.Add(eeo);
    }

    private void A_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int y = rnd.Next(buttons.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Count; i++ )
        {
            buttons[i].Visible = (i == y);
        }
    }

}
```